# How to send request from a service running on EKS cluster as a client to a differnt service running outside the network

Tags: client-server, amazon-eks, whitelist

Senario: I have two services lets say A and B.
At present service A is running on ec2 instances with an elb infront of it and makes call to service B. At service B side, we have whitelisted IP of service A to accept request only from the Whitelisted IP's.

Now we migrated service A from ec2 instances to EKS, I am a bit new to EKS concept, So I would like to know how we can how we can allow service A to send request to service B.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup NAT with Elastic IP address and route your cluster egress thru this NAT. You can then whitelist the NAT public EIP which doesn't change.